# Particle Filter without Laser Scans match

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to locate a robot inside a map. I have odometry information, IMU, magnetometer, pressure, a 2d map and the initial position inside the map. But I don't have the `/scan` topic to provide the correction step and use the AMCL package.  Is there a way to do localization with those?

I was trying to use or implement a Particle Filter Approach, for the prediction steps I will use sensor fusion, and for the corrective step I wanted to use fiducial markers in the map.

I was looking at this [tutorial for Particle Filter](http://wiki.ros.org/bfl/Tutorials/Example%20of%20using%20a%20particle%20filter%20for%20localization%20by%20bfl%20library) and this is something I'm looking want to have.

Thanks very much!

André Castro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284305/particle-filter-without-laser-scans-match/) by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-03**:
As you've noticed, AMCL works by comparing laser scans to a map to figure out where your robot is. If you don't have laser scans, that doesn't work. The tutorial you linked to is about bfl, not AMCL, and looks like it might be more relevant.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-03**:
I suggest you reword your question to remove the AMCL references and spend some time describing the sensors that you do have available for localization. It sounds like you might have some other sensors, but as you've described it now you only have an IMU, and you can't do localization with it alone.

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2018-03-05**:
Updated the question a bit more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to perform `SLAM` or `Localization`, you need both `Proprioceptive sensors` (Internal state like an odometer, IMU, wheel encoder) and `Exteroceptive sensors` (external state like laser scanners). You need to use internal measurements to perform prediction with a given motion model. For correction step, you need to use external measurements like laser scans.

In localization problem, particles are drawn according to internal measurements and motion model. Then, resampling is performed using external sensor measurements and observation model. If you are able to detect fiducial markers in the map, you can use a particle filter.

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2018-03-06**:
Thanks! For correction step I am trying the pose from fiducials. Actually there are no packages and I'm having a hard time trying to adapt [this](http://wiki.ros.org/bfl/Tutorials/Example%20of%20using%20a%20particle%20filter%20for%20localization%20by%20bfl%20library) example with BFL.

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2018-03-06**:
I even don't know if it's possible... But thanks anyway! If there's a possibility to customize, I'm chasing that.